# Does the orthogonal group act irreducibly on totally symmetric tensors?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

Consider the action of the orthogonal group $\operatorname{O}(d)$ on $k$-way tensors $(\mathbb{R}^d)^{\otimes k}$ defined by

$$Q(x_1\otimes\cdots\otimes x_k)=Qx_1\otimes\cdots \otimes Qx_k$$

and extending linearly. I would like to locate a proof that the invariant subspace of totally symmetric tensors $\operatorname{Sym}^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ carries an irreducible representation of $\operatorname{O}(d)$.

If we replace $\operatorname{O}(d)$ with $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ for some vector space $V$, then [Schur-Weyl duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality) gives that the corresponding representation in $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ is irreducible (see Chapter 9 in [Procesi's Lie Groups book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387260402)). In the case where $V=\mathbb{C}^d$, Theorem 1.9 of [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604183v1) suggests that the restriction of any irreducible representation of $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ to $\operatorname{U}(d)$ is irreducible. The proof is said to be contained in Chapter 12 of Carter, Segals and MacDonald's [Lectures on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521499224), but the closest result I could find (Proposition 12.3) gives that every representation of $\operatorname{U}(d)$ is the restriction of a unique holomorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^d)$. It is not clear to me that $\operatorname{U}(d)$ then inherits irreducible representations from $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^d)$. Furthermore, this result seems to leverage a relationship between $\operatorname{U}(d)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ known as [complexification](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Complexification_of_a_Lie_group) that is not exhibited between $\operatorname{O}(d)$ and $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: This is false. If $k=2$, $\sum_{i=1}^d e_i \otimes e_i$ is an invariant vector.

Comment: Will Sawin's comment corresponds to the fact that the identity matrix is a fixed point of the action of $O(d)$ on the space of symmetric $d\times d$ matrices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is classical that, as $O(n)$-representation,
$$
\text{Sym}^k(\mathbf R^n)=H^k\oplus qH^{k-2}\oplus q^2H^{k-4}\oplus\ldots
$$
Here $q=x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2$ is the quadratic form defining $O(n)$ and $H^k\subseteq \text{Sym}^k(\mathbf R^n)$ is the space of harmonic polynomials, i.e., polynomials which are killed by the Laplacian $\Delta=\partial_{x_1}^2+\ldots+\partial_{x_n}^2$. Moreover all spaces $q^lH^k$ are irreducible provided $n\ge2$.

Comment: "Classical" is nice. A reference is nicer :)

Comment: Well, "classical" means here "easy to find by searching the web". I found e.g. the Wikipedia article on "spherical harmonics" or section 5.6.4. of the book of Goodman-Wallach.

Comment: Let me just add that analogous thing is true for $Sp(n)$ and the symplectic form. For details see again Symmetry and representation theory by Goodman and Wallach.